# Why do gcc and clang generate so much code for std::find?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, codegen

I entered the following code into godbolt.org, and compiled it with gcc 10.1 and clang 10:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> V;

template<class InputIt, class T>
InputIt myfind(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value) {
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == value) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}

V::iterator my_find_int(V& v, int i) {
    return myfind(v.begin(), v.end(), i);
}

V::iterator std_find_int(V& v, int i) {
    return std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), i);
}
```

With either `-O3` or with `-Os`, both compilers generate about what I would expect for `my_find_int` (gcc 10.1, `-Os`):

```
my_find_int(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int):
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
.L3:
        mov     r8, rax
        cmp     rdx, rax
        je      .L2
        add     rax, 4
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rax-4], esi
        jne     .L3
.L2:
        mov     rax, r8
        ret
```

However, for `std_find_int`, with either `-O3` or `-Os`, they both generate *several dozen* instructions (gcc 10.1, `-Os`):

```
std_find_int(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, int):
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rcx, rdi
        sub     rcx, rdx
        sar     rcx, 4
.L12:
        mov     rax, rdx
        test    rcx, rcx
        jle     .L7
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdx], esi
        je      .L8
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdx+4], esi
        jne     .L9
        add     rax, 4
        ret
.L9:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdx+8], esi
        jne     .L10
        add     rax, 8
        ret
.L10:
        lea     rdx, [rdx+16]
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rax+12], esi
        jne     .L11
        add     rax, 12
        ret
.L11:
        dec     rcx
        jmp     .L12
.L7:
        mov     rdx, rdi
        sub     rdx, rax
        cmp     rdx, 8
        je      .L13
        cmp     rdx, 12
        je      .L14
        cmp     rdx, 4
        jne     .L23
        jmp     .L15
.L14:
        cmp     esi, DWORD PTR [rax]
        je      .L8
        add     rax, 4
.L13:
        cmp     esi, DWORD PTR [rax]
        je      .L8
        add     rax, 4
.L15:
        cmp     esi, DWORD PTR [rax]
        je      .L8
.L23:
        mov     rax, rdi
.L8:
        ret
```

According to cppreference.com, `myfind` is a valid implementation of `std::find` (they describe it as a "possible implementation" of `std::find`).

The behavior does not seem to be version-specific; the output of every major version of gcc going back to at least 4.9 looks similar.

It seems like `my_find_int` and `std_find_int` should be functionally identical, so why do both compilers generate so much more code when `std::find` is used?

Comment: I think it just unrolls it bu fails to vectorize the branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is simple: the implementation of `std::find` for random access iterators is not a simple `for` loop, but [something more complicated](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h#L2060):

```
template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Predicate>
    _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
    _RandomAccessIterator
    __find_if(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
          _Predicate __pred, random_access_iterator_tag)
    {
      typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::difference_type
    __trip_count = (__last - __first) >> 2;

      for (; __trip_count > 0; --__trip_count)
    {
      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;

      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;

      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;

      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;
    }

      switch (__last - __first)
    {
    case 3:
      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;
      // FALLTHRU
    case 2:
      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;
      // FALLTHRU
    case 1:
      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;
      // FALLTHRU
    case 0:
    default:
      return __last;
    }
    }
```

The loop is manually unrolled, so that each iteration contains not just one predicate invocation, but four invocations. `std::find` is implemented in terms of `__find_if` with the predicate being a comparison.

This implementation dates back to [SGI STL](https://www.boost.org/sgi/stl/), at least. Alexander Stepanov [explains](http://stepanovpapers.com/PAM2.pdf):

> Typically people unroll by `4` or `8` but not more. The main reason that people don’t go beyond `8` has to do with the law of diminishing returns. The point of loop unrolling is to gain a decent percent improvement in the ratio loop overhead to overall code. Starting with, say 30% loop overhead, unrolling by a factor of `4` leaves us with about 8% overhead. Unrolling by a factor of `8` brings it down to a 4% overhead. Overhead below 4% is commonly viewed as noise – results could vary from CPU to CPU, etc. In research we do unroll loops – 30% does not matter when we only want to demonstrate feasibility. But when it is time to transfer code to real applications then unrolling can be worth considering.